# How to aggregate multiple fields while filtering data by date

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I have the following query, where I join 2 collections by a single field `mainId`.

```
const interval = moment.utc().add(-5, "days"); // number of days may vary
return this.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'collectionB',
      localField: 'mainId',
      foreignField: 'mainId',
      as: 'validd',
    },
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        { "validd": [] },
        { "validd.createdAt": { $lt: new Date(interval) } }
      ]
    }
  },
]);
```

it works perfectly! But now I need to join those collection by another field named `vid`.

Tried the following *without success*:

```
return this.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "collectionB",
      let: {
        mainIdField: "mainId",
        vidField: 'vid'
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                { $eq: ["mainId", "$$mainIdField"] },
                { $eq: ["vid", "$$vidField"] }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "joined_results"
    }
  },
  { $unwind: { path: "$joined_results", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } }
]);
```

instead of receiving ONLY the results that exists in both collections (joined by the two fields), I get a duplicate of every row inside `collectionA`. (the `this` used in the beginnig).

If I have this data:

#### CollectionA

```
name: "first"
mainId: a2345e87-a388-4b72-ae2a-1cd69b7e1330
vid: 123

name: "second"
mainId: b2345e87-a388-4b72-ae2a-1cd69b7e1330
vid: 456

name: "third"
mainId: c2345e87-a388-4b72-ae2a-1cd69b7e1330
vid: 789
```

#### CollectionB

```
name: "first"
mainId: a2345e87-a388-4b72-ae2a-1cd69b7e1330
vid: 123

name: "third"
mainId: c2345e87-a388-4b72-ae2a-1cd69b7e1330
vid: 789
```

**Second attempt. Now following this [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#std-label-lookup-concise-correlated-subquery)**

```
  return this.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'collectionB',
        localField: 'mainId',
        foreignField: 'mainId',
        let: { vidField: '$vid' },
        pipeline: [{
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: ["$$vidField", "$vid"]
            }
          }
        }],
        as: "matches"
      }
    }
  ])
```

**Third attempt without success**

```
return this.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'collectionB',
      localField: 'mainId',
      foreignField: 'mainId',
      let: { vidField: '$vid', mainIdField: '$mainId'},
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                { $eq: ["$mainId", "$$mainIdField"] },
                { $eq: ["$vid", "$$vidField"] }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: 'validd',
    },
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        { "validd": [] },
        { "validd.createdAt": { $lt: new Date(interval) } }
      ]
    }
  },
]);
```

I want to return only `first` and `third`. Then I will add the rest of the filters from my original query. How could I achieve this?

Comment: You are missing `$` in your `let` and `$match`. Try again like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LtRPa_fVb45)

Comment: Hey, @ray. Thanks again! But unfortunatelly I keep getting as output all the 3 rows from CollectionA :S

Comment: @ray  Actually, removing `, preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true `  did the trick. Now I'll try to add the other filters.

Comment: yes, the playground relies on not preserveNullAndEmptyArrays to do the pruning. Sorry to inform you that, I am voting to close this question as the root cause is minor syntax issue.

Comment: @ray may I do like you showed and add the first filters all together?